# How to search a numpy array for a sub-vector?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array (in Python 3) and I'd like to find a sub-vector in it.
If I search for a full vector, this code works:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([10,5])
a[0] = [5,6,4,8,5]
a[1] = [3,6,8,5,3]
a[2] = [3,2,1,5,3]
a[3] = [6,5,6,4,6]
a[4] = [3,4,7,6,3]
a[5] = [2,3,1,5,2]
a[6] = [1,1,3,2,1]
a[7] = [6,5,8,8,6]
a[8] = [5,4,9,7,5]
a[9] = [1,2,7,8,1]

print(a)
search = [2,3,1,5,2] # correctly returns 5
i = np.argwhere(np.all((a-np.array(search))==0, axis=1))
print(int(i))
```

Ok, but I'd like to find this sub-vector:

```
search = [2,3,1,5]
```

How can I find it?

Comment: So it has to be contiguous, or can it have gaps? For example is `[2,3,1,_,5]` a valid vector for the subvector? It is always a prefix?

Comment: It has to be contiguous, but not always a prefix. It can be anywhere, say [2,7].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple numpy solution:

Search the raveled array and stop in first occurrence (you will be able to modify this into any type of search you deem fit including if your `search` list spans over multiple rows AND also finding multiple occurrences of `search` in `a`).

Following code assumes you are looking for first occurrence within a row of `a`:

```
for i in range(a.size-len(search)):
    if np.array_equal(np.ravel(a)[i:i+len(search)], np.array(search)) and int(i/a.shape[1])==int((i+len(search)-1)/a.shape[1]):
        print(int(i/a.shape[1]))
        break
```

If speed matters and `a`/`search` is large, save a raveled version of `a` into `a_ravel = np.ravel(a)` and numpy array of `np.array(search)` and use that inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way,

**EDIT** : The following code assumes your `search` vector starts at the beginning of the row

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([10,5])
a[0] = [5,6,4,8,5]
a[1] = [3,6,8,5,3]
a[2] = [3,2,1,5,3]
a[3] = [6,5,6,4,6]
a[4] = [3,4,7,6,3]
a[5] = [2,3,1,5,2]
a[6] = [1,1,3,2,1]
a[7] = [6,5,8,8,6]
a[8] = [5,4,9,7,5]
a[9] = [1,2,7,8,1]
search = [2,3,1,5]

s = search+[None]*((a.shape[1]-len(search)))
loc = np.where((a==s).sum(1)== len(search))
```

Output

```
loc 
(array([5], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this doesn't quite work. If ```a[5]= [2,3,1,5,0]``` this would have failed. Maybe ```loc = np.where((a==s).sum(1) >= len(search))```?

Comment: Unfortunately, this would also have failed if ```search = [3, 1]``` and ```a[5] = [2,5,1,0,0]```. You'd have got a false match here because of the padding of zeros.

Comment: You could pad with `np.nan`s instead. but then you're still assuming that the vector we're looking for starts at the beginning of a row, ie. we would have failed if ```a[5] = [7,2,3,1,5]``` even though it contains our search pattern

Comment: @Ralph Well spotted! In this case replacing the `0` with `None` should do. Try it out and see !

Comment: @Ralph yes that's correct, `np.nan` could also do, And yes the code assumes vector starts at the beginning of a row. I'll add that now

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([10, 5])
a[0] = [5, 6, 4, 8, 5]
a[1] = [3, 6, 8, 5, 3]
a[2] = [3, 2, 1, 5, 3]
a[3] = [6, 5, 6, 4, 6]
a[4] = [3, 4, 7, 6, 3]
a[5] = [2, 3, 1, 5, 2]
a[6] = [1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
a[7] = [6, 5, 8, 8, 6]
a[8] = [5, 4, 9, 7, 5]
a[9] = [1, 2, 7, 8, 1]

search = [2, 3, 1, 5]
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    strided_row = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        row, (a.shape[1] - len(search) + 1, len(search)), (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    )
    if (strided_row == search).all(axis=1).any():
        break
else:
    i = None
print(i)
```

Assuming that `search` is contiguous part of some row of `a`. [Documentation for as_strided()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). For example for the first row: `strided_row` is `[[5, 6, 4, 8], [6, 4, 8, 5]]` then we can search for `search` the same way as in question.

Comment: Any reason you set ```i = None``` before the ```enumerate```?

Comment: I want to handle situation when there is no `search` in `a` and do it wrongly). I edit answer. Thanks.